# Making a certain color transparent on an image

Tags: android

I have an image that is circular and I want to make the other junk in the image to be transparent. I've spent the last hour looking around and I can't seem to figure out how this is done for android. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: P.S. I tried making it transparent in GIMP and saving as a PNG, but android isn't liking that and fails to load the image.

Comment: I've used GIMP for Android PNGs before. Try again?

Comment: What is the pixel format of your image?

Comment: @Josh Brittain: Questions on SO are meant to be related to programming issues. Android has no problem with images of any format if they're created correctly. As with dmon, I've used GIMP to create images with transparent images and have had no problems with using them in Android apps.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: In OpenGL or DirectX you can define a certain color to be transparent, I figured there is something similar for android.

Comment: As for GIMP with PNG, I have one background image that works just fine, but this one doesn't load. The error that I get is java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value '@drawable/test' must start with #

Comment: @Josh: Standard ARGB with A being level of transparency/opacity. The number format is hex, i.e., FF = 255 and should be represented (for example) as #FFFF0000 for 100% opacity of pure red.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Android but on iOS pngs weren't loading for me when I made them in photoshop but when I made them in flash all of a sudden they would work! Try that first :)
Anyways, you want to google something along the line of "pixel arrays android code" you can create an array of each pixel, find an individual color, then make it transparent...
But I really think this is just a GIMP issue and you don't need to go through all of that hassle.

Answer (score 0):

what i can understand from your uncleared words is that you want to display transparent image of a normal image you have . so i would suggest don't do it through programming . create a transparent image through any image editor tool and use it .
if image is dynamic that you cant go in this way so use `Matrix` and `setAlpha` . search over net for both the terms